# Http Error 500 in Wordpress, second time in 15 days

Tags: php, wordpress, http, error-handling

I'm suffering a HTTP Error 500 in my Wordpress site. It's the second time in 15 days.

In error_log I have this:

```
PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in /home/xxx/public_html/xxxxx/wp-includes/default-constants.php on line 138
```

And looking for that element, I found this (line 138 is the last):

```
function wp_plugin_directory_constants() {
    if ( !defined('WP_CONTENT_URL') )       
define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', get_option('siteurl') . '/wp-content'); // full url - WP_CONTENT_DIR is defined further up
```

The site is working, but I cannot enter to wp-admin.

The first time my hosting restored the entire cPapel, but this time I would like to discover the origin of the problem.

Any ideas? Maybe any plugin is causing it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like call to `get_option` is causing the generation of `WP_error`. I would recommend you install a fresh copy of latest wordpress and copy over themes and plugin one by one making sure you dont get these errors. if you do get this error again, then the latest plugin you installed is to be blamed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The problem is that the error is not inmediate, maybe the site is working fine for several days before it appears again. So I find it dificult to know which plugin is causing it. But, anyway, if I install a fresh copy as you suggest, can I restore a backup? I have daily backups created with a plugin, but I don't know if I could miss something.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to restore a back up. If there is a difference in versions, then DB will ask permission for update database, but it shouldn't give you much grief. Please proceed with caution and backup the site fully first, especially if its a live site.